# Is this a U.S system to bail out?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Currently reading this [**article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/sham-candidate-helped-flip-florida-141301334.html) there is a line, says,

> **Artiles declined to comment to a scrum of reporters who chased him out of jail on Thursday once he posted a $5,000 bond.** “This will be decided in the courts, thank you,” he said.

Is Artiles bailing out?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. Also note the INTRANSITIVE ***to bail out*** is often used somewhat more figuratively to mean [***to stop doing or being involved with something***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bail-out). But people rarely intransitively bail [themselves] out of prison - it's usually a transitive usage, in that usually it's some wealthy friend/relative who ***bails someone** [out of prison]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Okay, anyways, thank you for both for clearing it out no matter what viewpoint you have about my question.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Dictionaries probably won't make it clear that intransitive ***to bail*** is extremely unlikely in a context like "I'm surprised to see you out and about today! I heard you were arrested in last night's barroom brawl", "Yeah, I was thrown in jail. **But I bailed**." This situation doesn't really arise where I live (UK), but I think most Americans would say "**But I made / posted bail**" there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It's also not unusual to hear "...but I was bailed out" or "«somebody» bailed me out" in that context.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Yes, that's my point. It's usually either transitive (I bailed *someone* out) or passive (someone bailed *me* out), not intransitive (I didn't want to spend the night in jail, so I bailed out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post a bond (in US English) is to pay a sum of money to formally promise that someone accused of a crime and being kept in prison will appear for trial if released. It can be paid by the accused person, or on their behalf e.g. by a relative or friend, or by a person or company who provides a bond as a service for a fee.

[Bond (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bond)

'Bail out', a phrasal verb used intransitively, means 'to jump out of an aircraft with a parachute because the aircraft is going to have an accident'

[Bail out (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bail-out)

It is possible to speak of 'bailing someone (or oneself) out' of police custody. One would not, in any English variant, speak of 'bailing out' of custody.

Comment: Without wishing to split hairs, there's Dan Cooper who **bailed out** of an American airliner with a lot of ransom money 50 years ago, not because the aircraft was in danger, but because he didn't want to get caught. And he never was.    https://www.fbi.gov/history/famous-cases/db-cooper-hijacking

Comment: Do we say that parachutists _bail out_ of the aircraft that takes them to the height and location of their intended jumps?

Comment: In fairness it does seem to depend on the dictionary consulted: Macmillan, Merriam Webster and Longman would agree. Others speak of aircraft emergencies. But Dan Cooper's is a remarkable story and I've never previously had a chance to slip it in.